# vim: Force specific syntax via command-line argument

Tags: vim, stdout, stdin, sql, syntax-highlighting

When I want to easily read my PostgreSQL schema, I dump it to `stderr` and redirect it to `vim`:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres dog_food --schema-only | vim -
```

This gives:

[image]

`vim` does not have a syntax highlight schema, because it has no filename extension when reading from stdin, so I use the following:

```
:set syntax=sql
```

Which gives:

[image]

Being the lazy developer I am, I would like to force `vim` to use the SQL syntax by passing a command line argument, saving me the choir of re-typing `set syntax=<whatever>` every time I open it with `stdin` data..

**Is there a way to set `vim` syntax by passing a command line argument?**

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use:

```
vim -c 'set syntax=sql' -
```

Comment: Note: Works for me even without the colon in the command.

Comment: Shorter variant: `vim '+set syn=sql' -`

Comment: Typically you're better off using `set filetype=sql` (or `ft=sql` for short); that will also load the indentation files and such and not just the syntax highlighting...

Answer (score 6):

```
vim -R -c 'set ft=sql' -
```

- `-R` opens Vim in [read-only mode](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-R). Your system may have the alias `view` for `vim -R`, but [Neovim does not support it](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/4366).
- `set ft` is short for `set filetype`. As [Martin Tournoij](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/33645/martin-tournoij) mentioned in [his comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/268897/timeline#comment_468419), setting the file type sets the syntax and more.

Answer (score 2):

You can even automate that by putting the command into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
augroup filetype
  au! StdinReadPre * set filetype=sql
augroup END
```

Comment: What might an example of filetype be, e.g. if I had an extension of  `.extension` that I wanted to set as html would I use `.extension` or `extension` I have tried both but neither worked, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @MaxCarroll Depends on what you want to achieve; this smells like a new question unrelated to the issue addressed here. But before you create one, try to search for it; chances are the answer is already somewhere in the web, and probably in the SE network, too.